# Как отменить rm -rf /* (debian)

Tags: linux, сервер, debian, vds

Умные люди поймут, что я хотел очистить текущую директорию, но удаление пошло с корня сервера.
Можно ли это как то отменить? 
Уже решил проблему через тех-поддержку. Хотелось бы иметь собственные решения на такую ситуацию.

Comment: Регулярный бэкап всего диска :)

Comment: Возможно стоит искать вариант не как восстановить, а как предотвратить. На некоторых системах `rm -rf /` вылетает с ошибкой `rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on ‘/’ rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe`, что в принципе должно спасать, но стоило мне добавить звездочку в конце, как у вас в примере, и удаление начало работать.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov: потому что `*` была раскрыта шеллом в список каталогов, из которых ни один не являлся корнем. В шелле wildcard'ы не доходят до конечного приложения.

Comment: Надо же, как в точку я попал=)

Answer (score 9):

советы на будущее:

1. делайте бэкапы.
2. работайте под непривилегированным пользователем, повышая привилегии (с помощью `sudo`) лишь для решения **административных** задач, которые и перечислите в `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: @VladD, а бэкапы???

Comment: Ну, бэкапы на мой вкус «слишком правильный» совет, наподобие «мойте руки перед едой». Про это все знают, и все (к сожалению) игнорируют. А вот идея о том, что такое несчастье могло приключиться только если сидеть в шелле из-под рута — более нетривиальна.